# Should I directly add a video to my website or upload it to YouTube and embed it to my website?

Tags: html, css

Should I directly add a video to my website or upload it to YouTube and embed it on my website?

Answer (score 1):

Embedding is a way to "safe traffic" from your own server, technically you would present a video from other websites, but you would be using youtube in the background. In my honest opinion embedding video is a much better approach compared to using your own website video.